# Trim not working on null characters

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have a really bizarre problem with trim method. I'm trying to trim a string received from database. Here's my current method:

```
string debug = row["PLC_ADDR1_RESULT"].ToString();
SPCFileLog.WriteToLog(String.Format("Debug: ${0}${1}",debug,Environment.NewLine));
debug = debug.Trim();
SPCFileLog.WriteToLog(String.Format("Debug2: ${0}${1}", debug, Environment.NewLine));
debug = debug.Replace(" ", "");
SPCFileLog.WriteToLog(String.Format("Debug3: ${0}${1}", debug, Environment.NewLine));
```

Which produces file output as following:

```
Debug: $    $
Debug2: $    $
Debug3: $    $
```

Examining the hex codes in file revealed something interesting. The supposedly empty spaces aren't hex 20 (whitespace), but they are set as 00 (null?)

[image]

How our database contains such data is another mystery, but regardless, I need to trim those invalid (?) null characters. How can I do this?

Comment: Let me guess your database string contains `\0` character, second share how you store data in DB datatype + give example how you query it

Comment: Data is inserted into the database by another service of which I have no control over. Due to NDA, I'm not allowed to disclose the query but suffice to say it's just a SELECT COLUMN of a varchar field.

Comment: A character with unicode code point 0x0000 is categorized as a control character, not as whitespace.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you just want to remove all null characters from a string, try this:

```cs
debug = debug.Replace("\0", string.Empty);
```

If you only want to remove them from the ends of the string:

```cs
debug = debug.Trim('\0');
```

There's nothing special about null characters, but they aren't considered white space.

Answer (score 5):

`String.Trim()` just doesn't consider the NUL character (`\0`) to be whitespace. Ultimately, it calls [this](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/char.cs,3b2919f97584ef55) function to determine whitespace, which doesn't treat it as such.

Frankly, I think that makes sense. Typically `\0` is not whitespace.

Comment: Unicode categorizes code point 0x0000 as a control character.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Christian's link shows that some Unicode control characters *are* considered white space.  It just happens that `\0` isn't one of them :)

Comment: Very odd that they've hardcoded in only a few of the characters though but perhaps there is a full call to `CharUnicodeInfo.IsWhitespace` somewhere as well. `Char.IsWhitespace` reports 25 out of 65536 code points as whitespace.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen They distinguish upfront between the character being "checked" for "is whitespace" is a "latin-1" character (everything with hex < 0xFF is - so 0x00 is as well). In that case they take the shortcut with the view hardcoded values. Otherwise they call the function you mention.

Comment: OK, that makes sense I guess.

Answer (score 0):

@Will Vousden got me on the right track...
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32624301/12157575

--but instead of trying to rewrite or remove the line, I filtered out lines before hitting the StreamReader / StreamWriter that start with the control character in the linq statement:

```cs
string ctrlChar = "\0"; // "NUL" in notepad++  

// linq statement: "where"
!line.StartsWith(ctrlChar)  
// could also easily do "Contains" instead of "StartsWith"
```

for more context:

```cs
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // dbl space writelines
        Out.NewLine = "\r\n\r\n";

        WriteLine("Starting Parse Mode...");

        string inputFilePath = @"C:\_logs\_input";
        string outputFilePath = @"C:\_logs\_output\";
        string ouputFileName = @"consolidated_logs.txt";

        // chars starting lines we don't want to parse
        string hashtag = "#"; // logs notes
        string whtSpace = " "; // white space char
        string ctrlChar = "\0"; // "NUL" in notepad++


        try
        {
            var files =
                from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(inputFilePath, "*.log", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                from line in File.ReadLines(file)
                where !line.StartsWith(hashtag) &&
                !line.StartsWith(whtSpace) &&
                line != null &&
                !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) &&
                !line.StartsWith(ctrlChar) // CTRL CHAR FILTER
                select new
                {
                    File = file,
                    Line = line
                };

            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outputFilePath + ouputFileName, true))
            {
                foreach (var f in files)
                {
                    writer.WriteLine($"{f.File},{f.Line}");

                    WriteLine($"{f.File},{f.Line}"); // see console
                }

                WriteLine($"{files.Count()} lines found."); 
                ReadLine(); // keep console open
            }
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException uAEx)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(uAEx.Message);
        }
        catch (PathTooLongException pathEx)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(pathEx.Message);
        }
    }
}
```